# SublimeREPL:R crashing

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am currently using Sublime Text 3 as my text editor. Recently I decided to try and use SublimeREPL to also have my R console in the same window. However, whenever I ask REPL to show me reasonable size chunks of my data frame it freezes for a good 30 seconds before displaying, if it ever gets around the displaying what I asked for.

Is anyone else having a similar issue? Is there a solution? If not, I think I'll go back to sending code to the original R console.

Comment: yes, `SublimeREPL` always unstable in my experience.

Comment: I'd use SendREPL with R-Box (and Terminator + tmux if you are on linux)